# istream_iterator and lazy evaluation

Tags: c++, lazy-evaluation, istream-iterator

Considering `istream_iterator`'s **lazy evaluation** I was wondering if I can rely on the initialized, but never dereferenced or incremented, iterator for a condition.

As an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    ifstream file("some_directory");
    istream_iterator<int> beg(file), eof;

    if (beg != eof) {

        //do something
    }
    else {

        cerr << "No Input!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Given this code sample, my question is:
Is it possible that `(beg != eof)` is evaluated `true` even if `file` is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given this code sample, my question is: Is it possible that `(beg != eof)` is evaluated `true` even if `file` is empty?

No. The standard says (24.6.1/1-2) says,

> After [`istream_iterator`]  is constructed, and every time `++` is used, the iterator reads and stores a value of `T`. If the iterator fails to read and store a value of `T` ... the iterator becomes equal to the *end-of-stream* iterator value. ... Two end-of-stream iterators are always equal. An end-of-stream iterator is not equal to a non-end-of-stream
>   iterator. Two non-end-of-stream iterators are equal when they are constructed from the same stream.

In other words, this is not as lazy as you think:

```
istream_iterator<int> beg(file)
```

It'll read the first `int`. If the file is empty, it fails and becomes the end-of-stream iterator right away.